# Drive high frequency output (32Khz) on 20Mhz Renesas microcontroller IO pin

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I need to drive a 32Khz square wave on pin 19 of a Renesas R8C/36C µController.  The pin is non-negotiable (the circuit design is already complete.)

The software design uses a 250 µsec interrupt for simulating multi-tasking, but that's only good for 2Khz full-wave.

Do I need to create another higher-priority interrupt for driving 32 Khz, or is there some other trick that I'm not aware of?

- [R8C/36C Hardware Manual](http://documentation.renesas.com/eng/products/mpumcu/doc/r8c/r01uh0095ej_r8c36c.pdf)
- [R8C/36C Software Manual](http://documentation.renesas.com/eng/products/mpumcu/rej09b0001_r8csm.pdf)

Comment: If having the 32kHz is critical, you're better off making it a separate interrupt completely.  Having it separate also makes the interrupt handler simple. Simple is good.

Comment: The 32kHz is critical.  I was hoping there might be some trick with on-board clocks or timers that could be used, but I don't see anything in the literature that specifically addresses how to do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the chip to offer that sort of advice; my comment was mainly from past experience on different chips.

Comment: If you needed 32KHz on a pin, and did not make that a timer output pin, it may be "complete", but is hardly what I'd call "design". ;)

Comment: Note that for a 32kHz square wave you need an interrupt rate of 64kHz.

Comment: @starblue;  I think @oosterwal understands that (from the "2Khz full-wave" statement; I have modified the timing in my answer to account for that oversight on my part - which only makes it even less feasible!

Comment: @Clifford I just wanted to make it explicit, because it took me a while before I realized that. From personal experience with an R8C I'd guess that 32kHz would work (I used 40kHz for software PWM), but 64kHz probably not.

Comment: @startblue:  It is a good point, easy to forget (I did), also your experience with RC8 may be worth elaborating on since I was taking a few educated guesses.  For example did you experience the kind of jitter I estimated, and was your application doing much other work besides?

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with the RC8 and Renesas don't say much on the subject of performance, but it is a CISC processor with typically 4 cycles per instruction, so lets estimate about 4 MIPS?  Some instructions are much longer with division up to 30 cycles.

So if you create a 64KHz timer and flip the output on each interrupt, you have about 63 instructions between each interrupt, you have the interrupt latency plus the code to flip the bit.  If it works at all, it is likely to constitute a significant CPU load and may affect the timeliness of other operations.

Be realistic, without a redesign, the project may not be viable.  You are already stressing it with the 4KHz OS tick in my opinion - the software overhead at that rate is likley to be a significant chunk of your CPU load.

**[ADDED]**

I previously suggested 6 instructions between interrupts - finger trouble in the calculator, I have changed that estimate to 63, and moderated my conclusion to "barely feasible".

However I looked again at the data sheet, interrupt latency is variable because the instruction execution is variable, and the current instruction must complete before the interrupt is serviced, the worst case is when the DIVX instruction is executing, when it takes up-to 51 cycles before the *first* instruction of the interrupt routine.  That's 2.55us, when you need the interrupt to trigger every 15.625us, the variable latency will impose significant jitter and constitutes 6 to 16 % of your total CPU time without even considering that used by the ISR itself..  Plus if the interrupt itself is pre-empted, or a higher priority interrupt is running when this one becomes due, further jitter will be imposed.

Whether it works will depend on the accuracy and jitter constraints of the 32KHz, and whatever else your code needs to get done.

Answer (score 3):

As many people have pointed out, this design doesn't seem to be very good from a hardware standpoint if the 32khz clock is meant to be generated with a gpio.

However, I don't know How desperate is your situation, nor do I know the volume involved. But if it is a prototype or very short series, and pin 20 is free, you can short-circuit pins 19 and 20, setup pin 19 as an input and 20 as output. Since pin 20 can be used as output from timer rd, you could set up that timer to output the 32khz without using any interrupts.

I am not a renesas micro expert, but I'm talking from what I've seen in the data sheet you attached and previous experience with other mcu's.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the datasheet for that chip:

[image]

It looks like your only real option is to use the pin as a generic output port.
the only usable output mode seems to be the generic output port.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't strap pin 19 to another pin that has the hardware to generate 32KHz and just make pin 19 an input? Not a proud moment but it was easy on a DIL package.

Could you call an interrupt every 15.6us and toggle pin19 then on the sixteenth interrupt do the multi-tasking stuff but that is likely to be wasteful. With an interrupt rate of 32Khz, setting pin19 then eighth of the time doing the multi-tasking decisions and the other seven times wait till a point you can reset pin19 and do some background code for less than half the CPU time